# How to type annotate parameters as 'proper' class instances or 'anything but primitives'

Tags: python, python-typing

I was wondering whether there is a type for objects that are 'proper' class instances.
Something that either communicates 'object should work with `setattr`' or 'anything but primitives' since even primitives are instances of object and have `__setattr__` methods. `Any` and `object` are to generic for this use case:

```py
from typing import Any


class MyClass:
    pass


def func(a: Any):  # <-- what should be used here instead of Any/object?
    setattr(a, "foo", "bar")


func(1)  # should emit a warning
func({}) # should emit a warning
func(MyClass())  # should work
```

I know that I could mess with `setattr` by tinkering with an object's `__setattr__` but I wouldn't expect this rather generic typing to be bullet proof.

Comment: The distinction you seem to be looking for is between built-in (including provided by extensions) types and user-defined types, but that's not something Python distinguishes at the type level. Python doesn't *have* primitive types in the same sense that languages like C and Java do.

Comment: @chepner: I would not mind if someone passes an instance  of `threading.Thread`. It just needs to be 'decoratable' via `setattr`. But you are probably right that there is no distinction between (`int`, `float`, `str`, `bool`, ...) and the rest. A `__dict__` might be a clue but it's about type annotation that should make things easier to comprehend and not harder.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that the type should support a certain method via a `typing.Protocol`:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol


class SupportsSetAttr(Protocol):
    def __setattr__(self, __name: str, __value: Any) -> None:
        ...


class MyClass:
    pass


def func(a: SupportsSetAttr) -> None:
    setattr(a, "foo", "bar")
```

However, note that according to **typeshed**'s builtins stub, each `object` supports this method: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L94.